# How the name of a song can be displayed when listening to local FM channel in MyRadio?

Tags: apk

In MyRadio app, when I listen to local FM channel the name of the song playing is displayed near the channel name. How do they do it? Does the broadcaster do some effort to display it?

Answer (score 2):

The broadcast channel is surely using **[Radio Data System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Data_System)** (RDS), also called **Radio Broadcast Data System** (RBDS) in the United States. It is now common practice (at least in my country) to transmit informations like Channel's name, programme's name or song's name with this system.

Your app simply receives and *parses* these data to display it, like a compatible radio set or car's radio would do.

Comment: @user51810 Shywim has put time and effort into answering your question here so that *everyone* can benefit. It's not polite to go pestering Shywim or anyone else to have things explained to you off-site, where it won't help anyone else, unless you're willing to pay whatever fee they ask for private consultancy.

Answer (score 0):

One imagines they have built in something like Shazam; an app which fingerprints audio then looks it up in a database (http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57617885-93/more-countries-can-shazam-songs-and-listen-on-rdio). I doubt the broadcaster has anything to do with it.